# Difficulty setting up an iterated integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to integrate the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}$ over the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x^2=4-2y$. Given that this region is between bounded by an convex parabola and in the positive quadrant it seemed natural to set up the integral as:
$$
\int_0^{2}\int_0^{4-x^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx
$$
With the bounds on $x$ coming from the intersection of the curves. I evaluated the inner integral by completing the square and substituting and got
$$
-\int_0^{2}\arcsin(1-y)
$$
Which I can reduce by parts at least to 
$$
-\int_0^{2}\arcsin(1-y)=\arcsin(y)y+\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}\mathrm dy
$$
Which is where I get stuck, although I think a substitution like $z^2=2y-y^2$ may work. Was this the right way to set up the problem? I can't imagine it was supposed to be this complicated.

Comment: do you have  problem with the last integral?last i mean $\int  \frac { y }{ \sqrt { 2y-y^{ 2 } }  } dy$

Comment: @Battani I should be able to get it, I'm worried that I overcomplicated this problem.

Comment: But when $y=0$, $x=2$, not $2\sqrt{2}$. There are no intersecting curves.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales ah ok I will fix

Comment: Substitute $y=1-u$ into the inside interval. In general if you have an expression of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ the substitution $u=derivative=2ax+b$ will simplify the integral. You may also divide the derivative by any common factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $\displaystyle\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-2y}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}dx\,dy=\int_0^2\frac{\sqrt{4-2y}}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}dy=\int_0^2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{y}}dy=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_t^2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{y}}dy$

$\hspace{.6 in}\displaystyle=\lim_{t\to0^+}\sqrt{2}\left[2\sqrt{y}\right]_t^2=\lim_{t\to0+}2\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{t})=4$

---

Alternate method:

$\displaystyle\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}dy\,dx=\int_0^2\left[\sin^{-1}(y-1)\right]_{y=0}^{y=2-x^2/2}dx=\int_0^2\big(\sin^{-1}\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\big)-\sin^{-1}(-1)\big)dx$

$\displaystyle=\left[x\sin^{-1}\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\big)-2\sqrt{4-x^2}\right]_0^2+\pi=-\pi+4+\pi=4$